# Are empennage airfoils always symmetric in conventional airliners?

Tags: airliner, airfoil, empennage

I'm specifically interested in these models: A319, B737-700, A220, E195-E2. You could call these conventional airliners, so I suppose the question is if these "conventional" planes have only symmetric airfoils in their horizontal and vertical stabilizers. Also, these empennages would never have supercritical airfoils?

Comment: The CRJs have negative camber on the horizontal tail and I believe a lot of airliners do, since they are generally making negative lift for trim.  The vertical is always symmetrical.  The horizontal tail of the RJ is definitely not supercritical, although the main wing is.

Comment: Interesting [chapter](https://www.fzt.haw-hamburg.de/pers/Scholz/HOOU/AircraftDesign_9_EmpennageGeneralDesign.pdf) on empennage design (Raymer).